# Error retrieving data from hive in flutter : List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Character>'

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-hive

I am trying to cache API data in hive DB. I have fetched the data from api and then tried to save in database. It got saved successfully but while fetching data it gives an error. It is not reading the sublist I guess. Here is the code for data class

```
List<Character> characterFromJson(String str) =>
List<Character>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Character.fromJson(x)));

String characterToJson(List<Character> data) =>
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Character {
@HiveField(0)
String url;
@HiveField(1)
String name;
@HiveField(2)
String gender;
@HiveField(3)
String culture;
@HiveField(4)
String born;
@HiveField(5)
String died;
@HiveField(6)
List<String> titles;
@HiveField(7)
List<String> aliases;
@HiveField(8)
String father;
@HiveField(9)
String mother;
@HiveField(10)
String spouse;
@HiveField(11)
List<String> allegiances;
@HiveField(12)
List<String> books;
@HiveField(13)
List<String> povBooks;
@HiveField(14)
List<String> tvSeries;
@HiveField(15)
List<String> playedBy;

Character({
this.url,
@required this.name,
this.gender,
this.culture,
this.born,
this.died,
this.titles,
this.aliases,
this.father,
this.mother,
this.spouse,
this.allegiances,
this.books,
this.povBooks,
this.tvSeries,
this.playedBy,
});
```

code for getting data from db:

```
List<Character> get storedCharacters {
  final box = Hive.box('data');
  var characters = box.toMap().values.toList();
  return characters;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this, assuming you have a `.fromMap()` method in your Characters class.

```
List<Character> get storedCharacters {
  final box = Hive.box('data');
  List<Character> characters = [];
  for(var item in box.toMap().values){
    characters.add(Character.fromMap(item));
  }
   return characters;
 }
```